# What is being compared in this Bitwise Operator if statement?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to understand a function that was written by someone else, but I'm have a hard time with the 2nd if statement that is inside the for loop. Can someone explain the logic here? What is actually being compared?

The data for the table CMS_ROLE has the following columns: ID, ROLE_MASK, ROLE_KEY. Both are varchar(100). ROLE_MASK is the title, such as manager, author, admin, etc. ROLE_KEY is a number assigned to the ROLE_MASK.

1 | Manager  | 1

2 | Author     | 4

3 | Admin     | 9

```
 function roleKeys($roleMask)
{
    $roleKeys = array();
    $this->queryBuilder
        ->select(array("ROLE_MASK", "ROLE_KEY"))
        ->from("CMS_ROLE");
    $roles = $this->queryBuilder->execute()->fetchAll();
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($roleMask) {
            if ((intval($roleMask) & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"])) == intval($roleMask)) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];

        } else if (!$role["ROLE_MASK"]) {
            $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
        }
    }
    return $roleKeys;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is my var_dump output. Still confused.

```
echo "intval role_mask : " ; var_dump(intval($role["ROLE_MASK"]));
echo "if statement : " ; var_dump( intval($roleMask & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"])));
echo "<br />-----------------<br />";

intval role_mask :
int 0
if statement :
int 0

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 1
if statement :
int 1

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 2
if statement :
int 0

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 4
if statement :
int 0

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 8
if statement :
int 0

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 16
if statement :
int 0

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 32
if statement :
int 32

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 99
if statement :
int 97

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 98
if statement :
int 96

-----------------
intval role_mask :
int 97
if statement :
int 97

-----------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple explanation of how bitwise operator works, it should help you understand what the programmer intended to do

Assume the following values for the variables:

CASE 1:

```
$roleMask = 5;
$role["ROLE_MASK"] = 5;
```

for the if statement:

```
if ((intval($roleMask) & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"])) == intval($roleMask)) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

the condition:

```
((intval($roleMask) & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"]) == intval($roleMask))
```

is resolved as follows:

```
5 in binary = 101
```

101 is then compared to 101 bit by bit 
bitwise AND follows these rules:

```
1 compared to 1 = 1
1 compared to 0 = 0
0 compared to 0 = 0
0 compared to 1 = 0
```

this gives:

```
1 compared to 1 = 1
0 compared to 0 = 0
1 compared to 1 = 1
```

101 in decimal is 5, so

```
(5 & 5) = 5
```

The if statement becomes

```
if ((5 & 5) == 5) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

which resolves to

```
if (5 == 5) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

CASE 2:

```
$roleMask = 6;
$role["ROLE_MASK"] = 7;
```

for the if statement:

```
if ((intval($roleMask) & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"])) == intval($roleMask)) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

the condition:

```
((intval($roleMask) & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"]) == intval($roleMask))
```

is resolved as follows:

```
6 in binary = 110
7 in binary = 111
```

110 is then compared to 111 bit by bit 
following the same rules as above,this gives:

```
1 compared to 1 = 1
1 compared to 1 = 1
0 compared to 1 = 0
```

110 in decimal is 6, so

```
(6 & 7) = 6
```

The if statement becomes

```
if ((6 & 7) == 6) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

which resolves to

```
if (6 == 6) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

CASE 3:

```
$roleMask = 7;
$role["ROLE_MASK"] = 4;
```

for the if statement:

```
if ((intval($roleMask) & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"])) == intval($roleMask)) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

the condition:

```
((intval($roleMask) & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"]) == intval($roleMask))
```

is resolved as follows:

```
7 in binary = 111
4 in binary = 100
```

111 is then compared to 100 bit by bit 
following the same rules as above,this gives:

```
1 compared to 1 = 1
1 compared to 0 = 0
1 compared to 0 = 0
```

100 in decimal is 4, so

```
(7 & 4) = 4
```

The if statement becomes

```
if ((7 & 4) == 7) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

which resolves to

```
if (4 == 7) $roleKeys[] = $role["ROLE_KEY"];
```

In this case, the comparison fails the test.. hope this helps

Comment: I totally get it now, but what an odd way he would choose to compare. Still trying to get his logic for filling the array for $roleKeys[]. This is a great first step in understanding that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of flags `$flags` and a bit mask `$bitMask`, the way to check if all of the bits in the bit mask are set is:

```
if (($flags & $bitMask) == $bitMask)
```

That's the expression you have, except with the arguments to `&` swapped (which doesn't matter).

For example, let's say `$flags` is `0x1110` and `$bitMask` is `0x0110`. If you AND those two values together you get `0x0110`. This passes the test since that value is equal to `$bitMask`.

Now let's say `$flags` is `0x1110` and `$bitMask` is `0x0111`. ANDing those together produces `0x0110`. That value does *not* match `$bitMask`, so the test fails. Not all of the bits in the bit mask were set in the flags variable—namely, the rightmost bit.

Comment: When I do a var_dump, I get either a 0 or a 2: var_dump( intval($roleMask & intval($role["ROLE_MASK"])))

Comment: I would have thought it would have been either 0 or 1. Confused.